# LessPopMoreFizzPedia Brown and the Mystery of the Missing Mentions

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, election

There's a new Response to my Declaration! I should go see what it is so I can respond to the concerns of my would be constituents!

[image: Inbox Screenshot]

Except, the newest response I see is my own. From over an hour ago, not a mere 6 minutes ago.

[image: Comments screenshot]

Going to the "Responses" tab on my profile reveals not just one, but *two*(!) comments that are nowhere to be seen on the elections page.

[image: Responses!]

Anecdotal evidence in chat suggests that this is happening to other candidates as well. This is a horrible bug. Please fix it.

Comment: Curiouser and curiouser... one of the aforementioned comments has *just* appeared.

Comment: And now several more in rapid succession. What in the world...

Comment: And now they're disappearing again. Something strange is going on.

Comment: Perhaps it is a test of your abilities to handle things that are intended to drive a normal person over the edge. Like a pre-moderation stress test. :P

Comment: Yeah!  I'm feeling really disenfranchised over here!!!!!

Comment: My comment vanished for me as well (the screenshotted one), but showed on my activity page. If it was deleted it wouldn't show on activity. Probably heavy caching or delayed updates on AJAXy requests.

Comment: Well, ++ for the Encyclopedia Brown reference, at least.

Comment: I've poked this around, we'll see if we can find summat about it.

Comment: yep, just posted a comment it hasn't shown up yet

Comment: New comments are still showing up at a trickle... 9 hours after being posted. I'm getting notifications, but it's frustrating to respond to questions and criticism and for it to be invisible a those criticisms get up voted.

Comment: awesome, I can go make a bald faced lie and you won't be able to see or respond to it for at least 18 hours :)

Comment: @spartacus I'll see it. Nobody else will.

Comment: Any info here?  My comment from 24 hours ago still hasn't posted!

Comment: @GraceNote I've got [two comments not showing up here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/election/4#post-151624) (only one comment of mine showed up), they [show up if I make another comment (screenshot)](http://i.imgur.com/IBY2jHD.png). They do not show up again if I refresh the page.

Comment: Indeed, there are now duplicate comments on my nomination, that only showed up after I responded to the single visible one.  Something's eating comments, and only spitting them out when you post your own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is fixed now.  There are a couple of things going on when we decide to limit the number of comments shown.  We have a site setting that sets a fixed limit, which is the limit @GraceNote was referring to in his answer.  However, that limit interacts with another thing we do, which is do a rollup of "top comments" because we don't want one of our blessed users' pithiest pithiness to be lost below the fold, to the detriment of all who seek wisdom.  So, in the event that there are comments that have been upvoted and there are also more than {comment-limit}* comments, we cause the upvoted ones to rise to the top so you won't miss them.

In the elections situation, we just weren't counting correctly because the view model for the elections view wasn't being populated completely.  Ergo, we just chopped off the comments that were beyond the limit.

<sup>* the limit is 15 by default, but can be configured site-to-site</sup>

Answer (score 10):

We did some testing and it appears that the issue was on comment limits. Election nominations only show up to 15 comments before expansion. However! There's no button to expand comments!

Posting a new comment auto-expands which is why people could see things only when commenting.

As a bandaid, we've increased the comment limit to 40 for now, but we're going to look at a more robust solution. Most likely adding back the ability to expand comments. Hence I'm not going to [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) this until we're happy with our solution.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't there a [status-deferred]/[status-planned] for this very purpose? :P

Comment: I could put status-planned, I s'pose.

Comment: I just like seeing the status tags in action. Makes meta feel a bit more organized.